# Enforce variable creation

Tags: c++, constructor

In c++, I have a class, say `T`. It is meaningful to construct an object as `T t();` but not as `T();`. Can the second version be blocked?

Comment: blocked.. from what? from who?

Comment: `T t();` declares a function. It doesn't create a variable. To invoke the default constructor on a new object, you **must not** use parentheses.

Comment: `T t();` declare a function.  You need `T t;`

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
T t; // invokes T() implicitly (t object is created on stack)
T* t = new T(); // explicitly (object is created on heap, pointer t to that object is on stack)
```

But

```
T t(); // declares function t of a return type T
```

Comment: How is this related to disallowing creating temporary `T`s?